# Weird behaviour with psearch (Vim)

Tags: vim, mapping

So this is a part of my `.vimrc`

```
" Mapping
nnoremap <F3> :cclose<cr>
nnoremap <F4> :w <bar> !cd ../build; make<cr><cr>:cw<cr>
autocmd filetype cpp nnoremap <F6> :Termdebug %:r<CR><c-w>2j<c-w>L
nnoremap <F12> :!cd ..; !ctags -R 
"nnoremap <C-[> :psearch <C-R><C-W><CR>
nnoremap <C-H> <C-W>h
nnoremap <C-J> <C-W>j
nnoremap <C-K> <C-W>k
nnoremap <C-L> <C-W>l
inoremap <C-H> <Left>
inoremap <C-J> <Down>
inoremap <C-K> <Up>
inoremap <C-L> <Right>
nnoremap <esc><esc> :silent! noh<cr>
inoremap " ""<left>
inoremap ' ''<left>
inoremap ( ()<left>
inoremap [ []<left>
inoremap { {}<left>
inoremap {<CR> {<CR>}<ESC>O
inoremap {;<CR> {<CR>};<ESC>O
```

As you can see I have a line commented, which I think is giving me some problems.
When that is not commented and I open vim this is what I got:

[image: screenshot]

A preview windows of the actual file is opened and I get into replace mode, also there are more weird behaviour, for example if I am in insert mode and I press `<Esc><Esc>` and press some arrow key vim insert a D or an U (as you can imagine depend on which key I press)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got this problem because `<C-[>` has the same keycode as `ESC`.

```
:h keycodes
```

then you search for "esc", you will find both have keycode 27. That is, you mapped `ctrl-[`, in fact, you mapped `ESC`.

In INSERT mode, when you pressed ESC twice, the first ESC brings you back to NORMAL mode, and the 2nd ESC triggers your mapping, the `:psearch` command.

Also when you press ESC in normal mode, the mapping is gonna be triggered as well.

The solution is also easy, don't map `<C-[>`.

Comment: I don't know why is trigered when I open a file.